# Get full path to file with Laravel Storage

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the Laravel 5.6 Storage API to store my files in `public/storage/images`. This works fine. When I want to retrieve a full URL for one of these files, I use

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->url('images/' . $url);
```

This returns

> http://localhost:1234/public/storage/images/foobar.jpg

But since my server is set up to ignore `public`, this address does not return the image. Instead, this address:

> http://localhost:1234/storage/images/foobar.jpg

returns the image. Is there any way to produce this address using Laravel's API, rather than doing an ugly find & replace?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: is this work ? change the disk config to 'url' => env('APP_URL').'`..`/storage',

Comment: @kenken9999 Close - I had to change it to `env('APP_URL').'/storage'`. If you add that as an answer I will mark it right.

Answer (score 0):

try this step to `ignore public` in path

```
1)Rename `service.php` to `index.php` in your root drive
2)copy `.htaccess` file from public folder and paste into root drive
```

now run your code without public in url

Answer (score 0):

create a .htaccess file in root directory and just add

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
```